# Does the scheduler get called after every system call api execution?

Tags: linux

For example, the fork() system call API. After creating the child process , it will come back to the parent process with the PID of the child.So my question is , will it invoke the scheduler  in the parent process  after the fork() system call API execution?

Answer (score 0):

What scheduler in the parent process? The kernel scheduler is [preemptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) (not [cooperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Scheduler#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing)).

Comment: I mean Cpu scheduler.